# Would fragmenting data into several independent secured files would make a system Quantum-Resistant?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, encoding, post-quantum-cryptography

In 2018 IBM is making available the first **quantum computers**.

This can be a disaster for most security systems based on computing power.

Could [this type of scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duCQP.jpg) bring a solution to this problem ?
[image]

Fragmenting information as above.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Regards,

Comment: Can you give a reference/link to which quantum computers will be made available by IBM?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this scheme tries to secure the data by holding the encrypted data back until the user can prove to have legitimate access to it (knows the password). In this case, your main fear shouldn't be quantum computing but other vulnerabilities as they've [been presented](https://www.rohos.com/2010/02/22/hardware-encryption-vulnerability-of-kingston-and-sandisk-usb-flash-drives/) in the past.

Further, the claim that a propietary (encryption?) algorithm is used should raise suspicion since the algorithm can't be analysed by the public crypto community. One downside of it is that any statement about is quantum resitance is purely speculative, but let's create a potential scenario:

- The attacker somehow got access to the encrypted data (memory dumping or intercepting communication)
- The attacker does not know the key nor can abuse a flaw (in the firmware) allowing him to recover it
- Big quantum computers are accessible to the attacker

Then, we have to do some assumptions about the system deployed by Ex0-Sys:

- The data is encrypted using a symmetric cipher like AES
- The key for the file is stored seperately on the USB-Stick which can not be abused in our attack model

When the cipher used to encrypt the file turnes out to be secure, the best the attacker can do is using Groovers algorithm, recovering the key in $O(\sqrt{2^n})$ or $O(2^{n/2})$. Algorithms like AES-256 would then have 128-bit security, which is reasonably safe.

However, since a propietary algorithm is used, there is a non-negible probability that it is vulnerable to classical attacks like differential or linear cryptanalysis, so the attacker wouldn't need to own a quantum computer.

Last but not least, to answer the question in the title:

- Fragmenting the key would either no effect if an attack can be performed on the data itself.
- Fragmenting secret keys needed to recover another key used for the symmetric cipher (typical hybrid scheme) may or may not be strengthen by fragmentation depending on the asymetric cipher used.
- Fragmenting the data into $n$ pieces would require the attacker to aquire them all and find $n$ keys if he wanted the whole data or the data is mixed up in a way requiring the attack to have all $n$ parts to recover it. However, it won't have that much impact since $n$'s impact is polynomal.

Comment: Please note that the password is only a small part of the Alph@TaV Vault Software security system.

To begin, it is imperative to have the 4 fragmented files resulting from the Alph@TaV Vault security process, namely the main secured file (* .ATD), as well as the 3 key files (* .ATK1 / * .ATK2 / * .ATK3) allowing the exploitation of the main one.

Comment: In addition, depending on the security mode (Vault Level 1, 2 or 3), it will also be necessary to know the Temporal-PIN-Code that was generated during data security process.

Then comes the fact that the user can define in advance on which physical computers the data can be decoded thanks to the use of our Ex0-UiD one-way hardware identification system.

Comment: There is also the possibility to define that the secure data can be decoded only from the storage units (USB / SD / ...) selected during the encoding process, this by adding a Hardware Lock option.

Finally, the user can also define a period of time during which the secure data can be decoded, period after which it will definitively be impossible to access the secure information.

Comment: For more information do not hesitate to consult our website as well as our blog.

https://www.ex0-sys.ch
http://ex0-sys.blogspot.com/

We have also made a Kick Starter campaign, you are very welcome to support us : 

http://kickstarter.ex0.ch

Thanks for your interest and see you soon .. ... .....

Best regards,

The Ex0-SyS Team